# CMake log files missing "Elapsed time" in some files only

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, logfile, elapsedtime

In my vastly complicated project I'm on at my work, I'm trying to add a post-build python script that analyze the log files, that seeks for:

```
1> Build started DATE TIME
1> Elapsed time XXXXXX
```

that is displayed in the build output window in visual studio.
When I anlyze all the log files generated by the compiler, I see that only some logs contains such text. I tried with all different verbosity levels, and still the same. Only about 50% of logs contains the "elapsed time" informations.
When I look into the output window, for one target it says for example:

```
20>Build started 2017-10-15 15:17:10.
20>     1>
20>InitializeBuildStatus:
20>         Creating "XXX.dir\Release_D\XXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
20>       CustomBuild:
20>         All outputs are up-to-date.
20>       ClCompile:
20>         All outputs are up-to-date.
20>       ResourceCompile:
20>         All outputs are up-to-date.
20>       Link:
20>         XXX.vcxproj -> C:\Work\XXX\XXX_RD.exe
20>         XXX.vcxproj -> C:/Work/XXX/XXX_RD.pdb (Full PDB)
20>       FinalizeBuildStatus:
20>         Deleting file "XXX.dir\Release_D\XXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
20>         Touching "XXX.dir\Release_D\XXX.tlog\XXX.lastbuildstate".
20>
20>Build succeeded.
20>
20>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.98
```

*(Project name renamed with XXX for reasons...)*
But when I check the file: OUTPUT/source/XXX.dir/Release_D/XXX.log it says only:

```
XXX.vcxproj -> C:\Work\XXX\XXX_RD.exe
XXX.vcxproj -> C:/Work/XXX/XXX_RD.pdb (Full PDB)
```

Only the linking part was logged.
But then when I analyze another log from previous dependency target, both in the visual studio output window, and in the log file it says like this:

```
Build started 2017-10-15 15:16:19.
Project "C:\Work\XXX\OUTPUT\YYY_output\Release_D\build\YYY\src\YYY-build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
Project "C:\Work\XXX\OUTPUT\YYY_output\Release_D\build\YYY\src\YYY-build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "C:\Work\XXX\OUTPUT\YYY_output\Release_D\build\YYY\src\YYY-build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Win32\Release_D\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
CustomBuild:
  All outputs are up-to-date.

... LOTS OF BUILD OUTPUT HERE

FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "Win32\Release_D\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
Touching "Win32\Release_D\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\ALL_BUILD.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project         "C:\Work\XXX\OUTPUT\YYY_output\Release_D\build\YYY\src\YYY-build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.99
```

What makes those logs so different?
How can I force the compiler (ev.cmake to setup the environment correctly) so that all logs has the same amount of data in it?

I need it so I can analyze how much time, each developer is wasting for waiting for the compilation to be complete (on average every day/week).
The project is multiplatform, however I'm interested about only windows builds. I found that msbuild.exe may be fed with /filelogger attribute where I can specify the output file, but I couldn't figure out how to tell the cmake to pass that attribute to msbuild. Unfortunately I am not a master of cmake, and after 2 days of continous googling I'm in the dead end.
I even tried using the

```
cmake -E time cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14"
```

but I've got an error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified
Elapsed time: 0 s. (time), 0 s. (clock)
```

However, even if I'd solve the error, It's not what I'm looking for, because it's an elapsed time of setting up the environment and solution, not the compilation itself.
Please advise.